# Bootstrap modal not showing completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal for my website. Recently, I used a jQuery plugin to build nav bar and some problems showed up. First, after I use `jQuery.noConflict()`, the program not recognize `$` anymore and I have to replace all `$` which jQuery. Second, when execute the command `.modal("show")`, the modal not showing completely, the whole screen is fade and I can type anything to modal's inputs. Here the [screen capture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwMO4kCm5oIOVnltMU9qME5pY1k/view?usp=sharing):

Can anybody explain to me what happened here? Thanks very much.

Comment: Can we have your code in fiddle.

Comment: The link to a screenshot you gave is broken.

Answer (score 0):

It seems their is a problem with the css. Make sure that you are loading bootstrap css only once.